# How to create unique name for each user’s input?

Tags: python, variables, syntax

```
x = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x(i) = input()
print(x, x1, x2,…)
```

It has an error. I know it’s wrong, but can I do it?

Comment: You can append them to a list and access the list via indices. Creating a new name for each input, names that you're not even going to use in code, doesn't really make sense. Variable names are something that you work with when writing code, you generally don't want your code to create new variable names or rely on variable names at all. Variable names are just a handy tool for the programmer, they're not really meant to be dynamically messed with.

Comment: @John Smith, what is your objective here? Could suggest a more Pythonic and cleaner way to achieve that objective.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Random Davis mentioned, you can append them to a list.

This snippet takes in `x` as how many user inputs to take, then adds each user input to `input_values` list:

```py
x = int(input())
input_values = []
for i in range(x):
    input_values.append(input())
```

Now you can access all the user inputs in the list all at once or individually using its index:

```py
print(input_values)
print(input_values[2])
```

Here is an example of user entering 5 numbers:
[image]